# Not getting RecordId on feedItem component in Aura!

Tags: community, aura, record, feeditem, spinner

I am new to salesforce and started learning it a few days back, here am trying to make develop a community and I developed one but getting a few 2 bugs that I need to resolve.

1. In my community I have a home(Landing) page and an Internal page that is feedItem. On the feedItem page, I am trying to get the record ID in the aura component in which I have defined the custom theme of the internal page but am not getting it.

this is the code below for your reference.

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,forceCommunity:themeLayout,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name="navBar" type="Aura.Component[]" required="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="navHeader" type="Aura.Component[]" required="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="searchBar" type="Aura.Component[]" required="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="leftSection" type="Aura.Component[]" required="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="rightSection" type="Aura.Component[]" required="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="footer" type="Aura.Component[]" required="false"/>
    
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />  
    
    <div class="main-container slds-grid slds-grid--vertical">
        <p>RecordId :{!v.recordId}</p>
        <div class="navbarheader slds-grid slds-col slds-size_12-of-12 slds-large-size_10-of-12 slds-medium-size_12-of-12 slds-small-size_12-of-12">
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_8-of-12 slds-medium-size_12-of-12 slds-large-size_12-of-12 slds-small-size_8-of-12">
                 {!v.navHeader}
            </div>
            <div class="navBar slds-grid slds-col slds-size_4-of-12 slds-medium-size_6-of-12 slds-large-size_12-of-12 slds-small-size_4-of-12">
                 {!v.navBar}
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="searchBar slds-col slds-size_12-of-12">
            {!v.searchBar}
        </div>
        <div class="body-main-conatiner slds-p-vertical_small">
            <div class="body slds-col slds-grid slds-wrap slds-size_10-of-12 slds-align_absolute-center">
               <div class="slds-col body-left slds-size_7-of-12 slds-p-vertical_small">
                    {!v.leftSection}
                </div>
                <div class="slds-col body-right slds-size_4-of-12 slds-p-vertical_small">
                     {!v.rightSection}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer slds-col ">
            {!v.footer}
        </div>
    </div>
    
</aura:component>
```

2. Whenever I am navigating from one page to another in my community the loading balls are hanging and don't go away till I refresh it.

````
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,forceCommunity:themeLayout" access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="navBar" type="Aura.Component[]" required="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="navHeader" type="Aura.Component[]" required="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="search" type="Aura.Component[]" required="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="stats" type="Aura.Component[]" required="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="Carousel" type="Aura.Component[]" required="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="leftSection" type="Aura.Component[]" required="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="rightSection" type="Aura.Component[]" required="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="footer" type="Aura.Component[]" required="false"/>  
    <aura:handler name="render" value="{!this}" action="{!c.handleSuccess}"/> 
    <div class="main-container slds-grid slds-grid--vertical">         
      <div class="navbarheader slds-col slds-size_10-of-12">
         <div class="slds-col slds-size_12-of-12">
           {!v.navHeader}
         </div>
         <div class="navBar slds-col slds-size_12-of-12">
           {!v.navBar}
         </div> 
      </div>
      <div class="searchBar slds-col slds-size_12-of-12">
         <div class="slds-col slds-size_8-of-12  brandingText">
            <span>Search the Community, get fast answers, quick tips, and best practices</span>
         </div >
         <div class="slds-grid slds-size_10-of-12 search-section">
           {!v.search}
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class=" slds-col ">
         {!v.Carousel}
      </div>
      <div class="body-main-conatiner">
          <div class="body slds-col slds-grid slds-wrap slds-size_10-of-12">
             <div class="slds-col body-left slds-size_7-of-12 ">
                  {!v.leftSection}
             </div>
             <div class="slds-col body-right slds-size_4-of-12 ">
                  {!v.rightSection}
             </div>
           </div>
      </div>
      <div class="footer slds-col ">
          {!v.footer}
      </div>
     </div>        
</aura:component>```


This is my home page theme layout and I think there is something wrong with the theme layout itself.

Please help me out.
````

Answer (score 0):

I got answer for 2nd question, 
Its for someone in future having the same error maybe this one can help you out.

Actually in my custom theme layout I didn't use {!v.body} instead I used  {!v.leftSection} and {!v.rightSection} that was causing this error if you're also having the Loading Ball hanging and using custom theme layout then try modifying your custom theme layout maybe that's what causing the error